# Firebase is Undefined in Quasar

Tags: javascript, firebase, quasar-framework

I am trying to get Firebase to work with my little test Quasar project.  I was originally following one of Danny Connell's tutorials but I have stripped the code down to the bare minimum so I can isolate errors.

My firebase import code is:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
console.log(" in file ", firebase)
```

Just so I can see what 'firebase' outputs as. In my chrome console I get this:

```
in file  undefined
```

Which is telling me it's not really importing firebase... correct? (I'm super new to all this so please be patient with me.)

My package.json file has these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@firebase/app": "^0.7.0",
"@firebase/firestore": "^3.0.0",
"@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"date-fns": "^2.23.0",
"emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"quasar": "^2.0.0"
```

},

I have tried various different syntax of the Import script, but since my package.json file has the "@firebase/.." I am assuming that is the syntax I need to import.

My Mac is running firebase -V 9.16.6 so I'm using the new modular version of firebase, I don't know if that's important.  But I don't have the compact reference, I don't know if it matters.  Maybe that is required in the package.json file? I don't know.

My Partner (also a programmer who works in react) thinks that my Mac isn't actually running the code/version that I think it is, but I don't now how to find out.

Anyway, when I try to throw in the firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) code I get even more errors, so I've been keeping that out for now.  I just need firebase to NOT be undefined, then I can go from there.

I would love help, thanks!

EDIT: I guess I'm supposed to edit this instead of answer... so another curious thing.

When I use the syntax:

```
import  * as firebase from '@firebase/app'
```

Then I do get a firebase object, and the initializeApp() function appears in my firebase object. (but from what I read this is not the ideal way to do this.) These are the results:

[image: firebase object screenshot]

But there is no 'firestore' function included in that ojbect.  Even though there is now a initializeApp() function.  Does this mean that I still don't have firebase installed correctly? That it's not pulling in all the functions that I need?

Comment: Which version have you installed?

Answer (score 1):

There are two *solutions*:

1. To comply with recent changes (Firebase version 9.12) use code:

   ```
   (for Auth and Firestore services)

    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
      const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "your key xxx",
      authDomain: "your project name.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "your project name",
      storageBucket: "your app name.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxx",
      appId: "xxxx",
      };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth();
    const db = getFirestore();
   ```
2. For backward compatibility with Firebase 8 (current version 9.12) use:

   ```
   import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

   import 'firebase/compat/auth';

   import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
   ```

See [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for full explanation

Answer (score 0):

an `@` symbol normally indicates a special path field

Try importing them as the following:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

For a complete guide, this is an ideal example of Firebase integration

- https://dev.to/quasar/to-the-stars-with-quasar-firebase-initial-service-structure-1fcf

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Maybe I'm confused... I want to use the firebase/firestore database from my own Quasar installation on my own server.  I don't want to use Google's firebase hosting service.  Just looking over that tutorial it looks like it's setttitng up Quasar on the google hosting service.

Comment: firebase doesn't care where it's hosted, so long as the domain is added to the 'trusted' domains URL it's fine. People prefer to use hosting since it is there.